# "Страда" и "страдать"

Tags: этимология

Слова "страда" и "страдать" очень похожи по звучанию, но означают совершенно разное. Родственные ли они?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти слова имеют общее происхождение. От сущ. *страда* «напряжение» (сил), «напряженная работа» > «тяжкий труд» > «мучение» с пом. глаг. суф. -а-ти образовано слово *страдати* >  *страдать* «испытывать сильную физическую боль или нравственные мучения». От глаг. страдати «мучиться, терпеть лишения, боль и т. п.» в праслав. период образовано с суф. -ть 
(как честь) сущ. *stradib>* страдть «мучение, страдание», которое развилось в соврем, *страсть* «сильное чувство». (Этимологический словарь русского языка Цыганенко Г.П.)